# Using dot product in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras-layer, fuse

I went through a couple of stack overflow answers related to dot product, but could not find the answer to my issue.

I am creating a model with two parallel CNN which get different inputs. I am using a simple CNN with 1 convolution layer. I am using the `GolabalMaxPooling1D` layer after feature extraction. 
At each side, the output is of shape `(None, 256)`.

The result obtained from the two pooling layer is merged using a dot. When I implement dot it gives an output `(None, 1)`.

I used dot so that features that have maximum value are enhanced and those with the minimum values are diminished when features from the two models are merged.

**Is there a way that I can use a dot for the model and get the output shape as `(None, 256)`?**

The following is how I am building my model

```
# input 1

input1= layers.Input(shape=(600,), dtype='int32', name='model1')

embeded_sequence1 = layers.Embedding(10000, 32) (input1)

conv_layer1 = layers.Conv1D(NO_OF_CONV_FILTERS,NO_OF_CONV_SIZE)(embeded_sequence1 )

activ_layer1 = layers.Activation('relu')(conv_layer1 )

global_max_pool1 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(activ_layer1 )


# input 2 

input2 = layers.Input(shape=(600,), dtype='int32', name='model2')

embeded_sequence2 = layers.Embedding(10000, 32)(input2 )

conv_layer2 = layers.Conv1D(NO_OF_CONV_FILTERS,NO_OF_CONV_SIZE)(embeded_sequence2 )

activ_layer2 = layers.Activation('relu')(conv_layer2 )

global_max_pool2 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(activ_layer2 )


# perform fuse classification

dot_product = dot(inputs=[global_max_pool1, global_max_pool2], axes=1, normalize=False)

fc_layer_fuse = layers.Dense(256)(dot_product)
```

Comment: The 'dot' tag is is inappropriate for your question.  In the future, read and know the meanings of the tags you select.

Answer (score 0):

So, by definition, the dot product between two vectors *a* and *b* is a scalar:

[image]

Indeed it is also called scalar product. Therefore, no, there is no way you can get a vector of length 256 using the dot product of two vectors.

If you want to combine the two resulting vectors from the pulling layers you could apply element wise product (see [multiplication](https://keras.io/layers/merge/)), or you might average them.

Comment: Thank you for your response